# RSA JWT Validation for Azure AD SSO with Golang

Tags: azure, go, oauth-2.0, jwt, single-sign-on

I have been working on a Golang web server and am currently trying to implement azure SSO so that people within my organization can use their work email to login to the site rather then creating a new independent account. The problem I have run into and spent way too many hours trying to fix is that when I get the JWT Token back from Azure AD using Oauth2 I can't validate the token using the RSA public key. I have made sure that I am getting the right Key id and modulus / exponent but it will not parse the darn Token.

Here is the code that I am using to implement the Oauth2 SSO exchange.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "crypto/tls"
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "website/Api"
    "website/Authentication"
    db "website/Database"
    "website/Routing"
    "website/Utility"
    util "website/Utility"

    "github.com/coreos/go-oidc/v3/oidc"
    "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2"
)

type Jwks struct {
    Keys []json.RawMessage `json:"keys"`
}

// Global Variables
var SQL_CONNECTION *db.Server_sql = new(db.Server_sql)
var AZURE_SSO Authentication.SSO = Authentication.SSO{}
var PROVIDER *oidc.Provider

//var AZURE_PUBLIC_KEY Jwks

func main() {
    ////////////////////////////
    // SSO Informtation Setup //
    ////////////////////////////
    configData := Authentication.SsoConfigValues(util.GetServerRootDir() + "backend/SSO.txt")
    PROVIDER, err := oidc.NewProvider(context.Background(), configData["issuer"])
    if err != nil {
        panic("Failed to get provider: " + err.Error())
    }
    AZURE_SSO.Scopes = []string{"openid", "profile", "email", "User.Read"}
    conf := oauth2.Config{
        ClientID:     configData["clientid"],
        ClientSecret: configData["secret"],
        RedirectURL:  configData["redirect"],
        Endpoint:     PROVIDER.Endpoint(),
        Scopes:       AZURE_SSO.Scopes,
    }
    AZURE_SSO.Oauth = conf
    AZURE_SSO.Secret = configData["secret"]
    AZURE_SSO.Appid = configData["appid"]

    mux := Routing.NewServerMultiplexer()

    PublicApiSetup(mux)

    // Setting up TLS //
    cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(Utility.GetServerRootDir()+"backend/certs/cert.pem", Utility.GetServerRootDir()+"backend/certs/privatekey.pem")
    if err != nil {
        panic("Failed to load TLS certificates: " + err.Error())
    }
    tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
        Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert},
        MinVersion:   tls.VersionTLS12,
        MaxVersion:   tls.VersionTLS13,
        // Other options
    }
    //////////////////////////////
    // Setting Up Server Object //
    //////////////////////////////
    httpsServer := http.Server{
        Addr:      ":8080",
        Handler:   mux,
        TLSConfig: tlsConfig,
        //TLSNextProto optinally specifies a function to take over ownership of the provided TLS connection when a ALPN protocal uppgrade as occured
        //ConnState specifies an optional callback function that is called when a client connection changes state
        BaseContext: func(l net.Listener) context.Context {
            ctx := context.WithValue(context.Background(), util.SERVER_ADDR, l.Addr().String())
            var ipAddr string = string(l.Addr().(*net.TCPAddr).IP.String())
            var port string = fmt.Sprint(l.Addr().(*net.TCPAddr).Port)
            ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, "IP", ipAddr)
            ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, "Port", port)
            return ctx
        },
        ReadTimeout:  20 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout: 20 * time.Second,
        IdleTimeout:  100 * time.Second,
        // ConnContext: optionally specifies a function that modifies the context used for a new connection c.
    }

    //////////////////////////
    // Starting HTTP Server //
    //////////////////////////
    err = httpsServer.ListenAndServeTLS("", "")
    if errors.Is(err, http.ErrServerClosed) {
        fmt.Printf("Web server closed\n")
    } else if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error listening for web server: %s\n", err)
    }
}

func PublicApiSetup(m *Routing.Multiplexer) {

    m.HandleFunc("/submit/login/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        http.Redirect(w, r, AZURE_SSO.Oauth.AuthCodeURL("state-token", oauth2.SetAuthURLParam("prompt", "login")), http.StatusFound)
    })

    m.HandleFunc("/callback", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Println("Login Callback Route Hit!")
        // Checking for valid state
        if r.URL.Query().Get("state") != "state-token" {
            http.Error(w, fmt.Sprintf("Invalid Callback State: %s", r.URL.Query().Get("state")), http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }
        // Exachanging Authorization code for token
        fmt.Println("Exchanging Authorization Code for Token")
        code := r.URL.Query().Get("code")
        oauthToken, err := AZURE_SSO.Oauth.Exchange(r.Context(), code)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, fmt.Sprintf("Failed to exchange code for token:\n\tCode: %s\n\tError: %s\n", code, err), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }

        fmt.Printf("Oauth2 Token Valid: %v\n", oauthToken.Valid())

        // Parsing the Access Token
        jwtToken, err := jwt.Parse(oauthToken.AccessToken, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {

            // Validating the Signing Method
            if _, ok := token.Method.(*jwt.SigningMethodRSA); !ok {
                return nil, fmt.Errorf("unexpected signing method: %v", token.Header["alg"])
            }

            // Getting the Public Key
            fmt.Println("Pulling Azure Public Keys!")
            resp, err := http.Get("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys")
            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
            defer resp.Body.Close()
            var jwks *Authentication.JWKS = new(Authentication.JWKS)
            err = json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(jwks)
            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }

            // Getting the Key ID
            fmt.Println("Getting Key ID")
            targetid, err := getKidFromToken(oauthToken.AccessToken)
            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }

            // Getting Correct Public Key
            var AzurePublicKey Authentication.JWK
            for _, key := range jwks.Keys {
                if key.Kid == targetid && key.Use == "sig" && key.Kty == "RSA" {
                    AzurePublicKey = key
                }
            }

            // convert JWK to RSA
            fmt.Println("Converting JWK to RSA")
            n_bytes, _ := base64.RawURLEncoding.DecodeString(AzurePublicKey.N)
            e_bytes, _ := base64.RawURLEncoding.DecodeString(AzurePublicKey.E)
            n := big.NewInt(0).SetBytes(n_bytes)
            e := int(big.NewInt(0).SetBytes(e_bytes).Int64())

            key := &rsa.PublicKey{N: n, E: e}

            // Returning the Public Key
            return key, nil
        })

        // Printing the Access Token
        fmt.Printf("Access Token:\n%v\n", jwtToken)
        // Printing email from ID Token
        //fmt.Printf("Account Email: %s\n", userInfo.Email)

        fmt.Printf("Login Successful!\n")

        http.Redirect(w, r, "/home/", http.StatusFound)
    })
}
```

Here are the JWK Structures:

```
type JWK struct {
    Kid string `json:"kid"`
    Kty string `json:"kty"`
    Use string `json:"use"`
    N   string `json:"n"`
    E   string `json:"e"`
}

type JWKS struct {
    Keys []JWK `json:"keys"`
}
```

If someone could tell me what is wrong where I would be very appreciative as I have spent 25+ hours on this!

I am 99% sure that the issue is in the anonymous function that is passed into the jwt.parse() function.